# Where do I find reference dll for System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, assembly-references

We are upgrading a VS solution from SP2010 to SP2013. We are using VS2010 and Windows Server 2012 OS.

Can you tell me where is the DLL for System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting; located?
The error I get is:-

> Error 7592    The type or namespace name 'DataVisualization' does not
>   exist in the namespace 'System.Web.UI' (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)   C:\dev\Project\MyPartsControl.ascx.cs

I was browsing for help and got this [link](http://matthewyarlett.blogspot.in/2012/02/adding-graphs-to-sharepoint-webparts.html) which mentions to look under: c:\program files (x86)\Microsoft Chart Controls\Assemblies. There is no c:\program files (x86)\Microsoft Chart Controls directory in my computer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is present here

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5

When adding dll references click on Framework and scroll down, you should be able to see this:
[image]

Comment: OK, I was trying to browse and search  and I forgot to check it under Assembly->Framework :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6728710/system-web-ui-datavisualization-charting-missing-error-in-net-4-0

> Do you reference it in your web.config

•under the controls tag (path: "< system.web>") :

```
< add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
```

•under "< httphandlers>") :

```
< add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/>
```

http://forums.asp.net/t/1698336.aspx?How+to+create+a+flipcart+like+panel+for+showing+products+in+gridview