# SharePointWebControls DateTimeField change format

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

i want to change the format of Field "Modified"

```
<SharePointWebControls:DateTimeField Name="Modified">
```

on my layout to this format : 1 january 2014 instead of
01/01/2014 00:00
is it possible?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve this

1. Create a new Class that inherits DateTimeField and add a property which displays the new format. [Detailed steps](http://bilalasmar.wordpress.com/2012/07/16/render-custom-date-format-for-datetime-field-in-page-layouts/)
2. Using Inline code in place of the control

   ```
   <%=SPContext.Current.ListItem["Modified"] != null? (new DateTime(SPContext.Current.ListItem["Modified"].toString()).ToString("dd/mm/yyyy hh:MM"): string.Empty %>
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the second way gives me an SPContext null at runtime, i'm trying to implement the first one but i can't find the library System.web.UI

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/91971/where-do-i-find-reference-dll-for-system-web-ui-datavisualization-charting